# Name of cleat-style tripod mounting head

Tags: tripod-heads, equipment-identification

What is this particular mounting head type called? All I know is it seems fairly common (I don't know much about photography equipment -- but I need to order some more compatible heads):

[image]

The tripod on the left is a Manfrotto Compact Advanced Smart (MKSCOMPACTADV). The cleat on the camera on the right was just hacked together in our machine shop, so while it does fit in the head, it might not visually resemble a more standard-conforming cleat -- sorry about that.

The mount accepts a cleat that is *roughly* 2-1/8" (55mm) wide and 1-1/2" (37mm) high on the smaller camera side. There are also two small shelfs on either side of the receiving end that look to provide the optional ability to make a cleat that can't be installed upside down. There is a locking lever on the top of the receptacle.

Does this mounting style have a name or other term that I can use when searching for camera mounts to make sure I end up with something compatible?

Note that I'm referring to the interface between the cleat and the tripod, *not* the three-screw interface between the cleat and the camera. Also I am not concerned about the pan/tilt ability of the whole head, just the shape of that mounting interface.

If it matters, I'm in the United States -- not sure if there's different standards globally.

Comment: If you're interested in customising RC2-style QR plates, some of the cheap eBay ones are easier to work with (both the plate and the clamp). Also as Manfrotto are Italian (UK-owned) their designs will probably  be metric except for the 1/4" screw into the camera and 3/8" screw (on some models) into the bottom of the clamp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quick release plate that was originally supplied with your tripod is the [Manfrotto 200LT-PL plate](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1118088-REG/manfrotto_200lt_pl_quick_release_plate.html).

[image]

It's a variation of several slightly different plates made by Manfrotto that fit the RC2 (formerly called Q2) quick release system.

The standard [200PL plate](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/878358-REG/Manfrotto_200PL_Mounting_Plate.html) includes [a removable "vhs" anti-twist pin](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/105856/15871) for use with cameras, mostly video cameras but also some DSLRs, that include a second hole for an anti-twist pin.

[image]

Any plate that is "RC2" or "Q2" compatible should fit your tripod. There are many third party makers of RC2 type QR plates.

There are also newer Manfrotto plates that fit both the RC2 and Arca-Swiss type systems, such as the [200PL-Pro](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1375463-REG/manfrotto_200pl_pro_200pl_plate_aluminium_rc2.html)

[image]

Note that the Manfrotto RC2 QR system is their most common one, but they also have other QR systems, such as RC4 (410PL), RC5 (501Pl, 503PL), RC0 (hexagonal), Q6, 357, 384 (dovetail), 785, etc. Just looking for a "Manfrotto plate" might get you one of those others which will not fit the RC2 base on your tripod head.

> Thanks; so it's proprietary to manfrotto, but manfrotto has some dominance over the industry there so it's also fairly common. Do I understand that correctly?

In the past, Manfrotto QR systems were more common than they presently are. Arca-Swiss type systems have increased in popularity in the last decade or two. But the Manfrotto RC2 system is still fairly widespread and no single system "dominates" the industry.

Also, please note that [not all "Arca-Swiss" type plates fit all "Arca-Swiss" type receivers](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/101317/15871), either. There are slight differences in plate widths, the angles of the bevels, and the shape of the corners where the bevels meet the bottom of the plate that sometimes will prevent a specific plate from fitting a specific receiver.

Answer (score 4):

The head is a 3D Compact, it takes a Manfrotto 200LT-PL plate. You can also use the 200PL plate, the newer 200LT-PL is a bit lighter and sturdier.

There are aftermarket equivalents.

Comment: Thanks; so it's proprietary to manfrotto, but manfrotto has some dominance over the industry there so it's also fairly common. Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: Manfrotto doesn't dominate, the Arca-Swiss "standard" is very popular. But you'll find no-name copies of the Manfrotto plate if you don' t want to pay the Manfrotto price.

Comment: @Jason C:  Yes.  I don't know that I'd call Manfrotto dominant anymore, but very common.

Comment: I might switch us over to arca-swiss based on this. The plates look just as easy to machine. Thanks everybody.

Comment: Please note that not all "Arca-Swiss" type plates fit all "Arca-Swiss" type receivers. There are slight differences in the angles of the bevels and the shape of the corners that sometime prevent a specific plate from fitting  a specific receiver.

Answer (score 3):

Hope I'm understanding you correctly.

The part mounted to the camera is called a quick release plate. The plate engages and is clamped to the tripod head with a quick-release clamp. The QR plate must be compatible with the QR clamp.

There are two major clamp/plate types (maybe more) commonly seen: Manfrotto and Arca-Swiss.  Manfrotto seems to continue to go their own way, which is fine because what they make works.  Arca-Swiss is becoming more and more ubiquitous, being supported by most head and plate manufacturers (other than Manfrotto).

For your Manfrotto head/clamp, you'll look for ["Manfrotto Quick Release Plate"](https://www.google.com/search?rls=ig&source=hp&ei=LrWCXbuPI4fz-gT80abYAg&q=manfrotto+quick+release+plate&oq=manfrotto+quick+release+plate&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.2084.12495..13476...1.0..0.198.2585.27j3......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i131j0i13.txem3tlENSc&ved=0ahUKEwi73veIu9vkAhWHuZ4KHfyoCSsQ4dUDCAc&uact=5)

Comment: There are multiple Manfrotto QR systems. RC2 is the most common, but there is also RC4 (410PL), RC5 (501Pl, 503PL), RC0 (hexagonal), Q6, 357, 384 (dovetail), 785, etc.

Comment: @MichaelC Manfrotto even has some Arca Swiss compatible heads now too

Comment: Yeah, there's a picture of one included in my answer to this question.